# How to link a library .a with f2py?

Tags: python, numpy, libraries, f2py

I'm trying to interface CUTEst with python using [ugly](https://github.com/lpoo/ugly).  I tried to use f2py like so:

```
f2py -c -m ugly \
 /home/gabriel/Documentos/ugly/src/gen77/gen77_main.f \
 /home/gabriel/Documentos/ugly/src/gen77/gen77.f \
 ELFUN.f GROUP.f RANGE.f \
 -L/home/gabriel/Documentos/ugly/objects/pc64.lnx.gfo/double \
 -lcutest
```

where `libcutes.a` is in `/home/gabriel/Documentos/ugly/objects/pc64.lnx.gfo/double`.  `f2py` did not generate the file `ugly.os` and gave this message:

> /usr/bin/ld: /home/gabriel/Documentos/ugly/objects/pc64.lnx.gfo/double/libcutest.a(usetup.o): no se puede usar la reubicación R_X86_64_32S contra `.rodata.str1.1' cuando se hace un objeto compartido; recompile con -fPIC

On the other hand if I compile with gfortran it works.

Answer (score 0):

To use code in an object file from Python, the object file must be compiled to use [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) so that the linker can include it as a part of a shared object. The error is saying that the library `.rodata.str1.1` wasn't compiled to use position independent code, so it can't be included in a shared object. You need to recompile the library you are linking against and pass the additional flag `-fPIC` to gcc/gfortran when you compile it.